# feature selection of trainingSet (in Cross Valdation) in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, feature-selection

how can I apply feature selection of trainingSet with "caret"?
It would be nice if there was an example of this.

```
Daten = data.frame(Daten)
cn <- colnames(Daten)

for (i in cn[401:ncol(Daten)]) {
  set.seed(222)
  CF <- createFolds(Daten[,i], k = 10 , list = TRUE , returnTrain = TRUE)
  for(p in CF) {
  trSet <- data.frame(cbind(Daten[p,1:100], i=Daten[p,i])) 
  tsSet <- data.frame(cbind(Daten[-p,1:100], i=Daten[-p,i]))
  tr<-train(
  as.formula(paste(i, "~.", sep = "")), 
  trSet , 
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl() 
)
```

Comment: Have a look at the `filterVarImp` function, if you want a caret solution.

Comment: I looked at it but it didn't work.
should be like this or something else? :
filter <- filterVarImp (as.matrix (trainingSet), full_SPL [, 101: 107])